# How to declare variable in gradle and print it in another gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am new in gradle. I did some research on how to declare a variable in gradle and found somethings in build.gradle. My problem is that how to declare a variable whose value is changed in some conditions and access the variable another gradle file which is my own custom.gradle

I am not sure this is the correct way to declare a variable.

```
defaultConfig {
   buildConfigField "boolean", "INTERNET_CHECK", "true"
}
```

After that I tried to print the variable in another custom.gradle, it gives an error. Following is how I print the variable in custom.gradle

```
println(INTERNET_CHECK)
println(BuildConfig.INTERNET_CHECK)
```

The error is:

```
 Could not get unknown property 'INTERNET_CHECK' for DefaultConfig_Decorated{................}
```

And another thing is that it does not assign another value in the INTERNET_CHECK in some condition blocks like `if/else` and print the variable it gives `null` and also not assign value in another variable.

Answer (score 1):

Vivek, i don't understand your error.
My observations

```
1.  buildConfigField "boolean", "SUPPORTS_THIRD_PARTY_SYSTEMS", "" + SUPPORTS_THIRD_PARTY_SYSTEMS

You need to define this variable SUPPORTS_THIRD_PARTY_SYSTEMS.

2. logger.error(BuildConfig.BUILD_TIME + " ")
   It could be logger.error("BuildConfig.BUILD_TIME=" + BUILD_TIME)

3. One example on how to print data defined in defaultConfig {} block.
println defaultConfig.targetSdkVersion.mApiLevel
```

app/build.gradle to use signconfigs in different flavor.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    flavorDimensions "default"
    lintOptions {
        // ignore lint errors related with following issue ID
        disable 'MissingTranslation', 'NotSibling', 'ExtraTranslation'
    }
    ext{
        APP_LABEL = "@string/app_label"
        APP_ICON = "@drawable/app_icon"

    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ranjan.example"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        buildToolsVersion = rootProject.buildToolsVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig null
            // this make the debug build take the flavor certificate instead of google debug one
        }
        release {
            // Don't do code optimization, it is creating issue with NDK
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        XYZ {
            keyAlias 'asXYZ'
            keyPassword 'ASXYZ02018#033'
            storeFile file('keystore/xyz.keystore')
            storePassword 'AXY02018#033'
        }

        //add another block for new sign config
    }

    productFlavors {
        ABCD {
            // application ID change is not working properly in middleware
            applicationId "com.ranjan.abcd"

            def ApplicationName = "com.ranjan.newApp"

            //Use signconfig defined earlier
            signingConfig signingConfigs.XYZ

            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel: APP_LABEL, applicationIcon: APP_ICON, applicationBanner: APP_BANNER]

     .

            buildConfigField("String", "APP_NAME", "\"${ApplicationName}\"")

        }

        //add other block for new flavor
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/rs']
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDirs = []
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = []
        }
        test{
            java.srcDirs = ['test']
        }
        productFlavors.all {
            flavor ->
             if (flavor.name.startsWith("ABCD")) {

                    getProperty(flavor.name + "Debug").assets.srcDirs = ["src/main/assets"]
                    getProperty(flavor.name + "Release").assets.srcDirs = ["src/main/assets"]
                    getProperty(flavor.name + "Debug").jniLibs.srcDirs = ["src/main/jniLibs"]
                    getProperty(flavor.name + "Release").jniLibs.srcDirs = ["src/main/jniLibs"]
             }
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
        exclude  'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

}
```

Comment: if you need a whole project i will provide you..this project is open source for themer i need some modification in product flavour

Answer (score 0):

println shall work, if that does not work use logger. look into this https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#sec:sending_your_own_log_messages

For variable declaration and use refer this                                                    https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code

Comment: Thanks sir for giving me advice...I used this option ..                                                                buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"0\"")                                                        and print in same file like this in                                                                                                logger.error(BuildConfig.BUILD_TIME + " ")                                                                  its give error

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'BuildConfig' for DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=24, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=28, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null,  } of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.

Comment: share your build.gradle from root and app module.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18GKk-O3VE7p6SQ935Lj5fygOLX65nkrj)          link of google drive    @Ranjan Sir

Comment: vivek, in actual scenario where do you want to use this variable 'BUILD_TIME'.?

Comment: actually sir i have flavour app in which i need to change the play console licence key with apk signature ...According to that i need to change the value through gradle value .First i need to find flavour version after that i have to change all three license key and apk signature